# Simple Blog module for Prestashop. I only want to contain the blog to one address www.site.com/blog. Right now appears on all product category pages

Tags: module, blogs, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I got the free version: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/1075163-module-simple-blog-%E2%80%93-free-prestashop-blog-module/

There is enough functionality for me right now, but there is no option to control where the blog content appears, only one button "disable on home page".
Is there a way to only contain it to /blog and for the blog categories to overlap my product categories

Tried reaching out to support, but still no answer

Answer (score 0):

As I see, this module has no configuration page. So you have to define 'ETS_BLOG_ALIAS' field directly in your database ('ps_configuration' table)